# Excel VBA Stopwatch: add pause button?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a stopwatch with a start/stop/clear button that posts the time to other cells in my spreadsheet. I want to add a pause button to allow users to pause and resume the timer where they left off, but it kept resuming and adding the time passed in the interim to the total. For example, I hit start and wait 5 minutes, then click pause at 5:00. I wait 2 more minutes, then click resume, and the timer picks back up at 7:00, 7:01, 7:02, etc. How do I create an effective pause/resume button and tell excel not to include the time passed when it resumes counting?

```
    Dim NextTick As Date, t As Date
Sub StartStopWatch()
t = Time
Call StartTimer
End Sub

Sub StartTimer()
NextTick = Time + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Range("M1").Value = Format(NextTick - t - TimeValue("00:00:01"), "hh:mm:ss")
Application.OnTime NextTick, "StartTimer"

End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextTick, Procedure:="StartTimer", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub ResetTimer()
Range("M1").ClearContents
Range("N1").ClearContents
Range("L2").ClearContents
End Sub

Sub PauseButton()

If Range("L2").Value = "" Then

    Range("L2").Value = "Paused"

    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextTick, Procedure:="StartTimer", Schedule:=False

Else
    Range("L2").ClearContents
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextTick, Procedure:="StartTimer", Schedule:=True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: where is your `Sub PauseTimer()`?

Comment: I've added in the attempt at a pause button.

Answer (score 1):

I think like this

```
Public blResume As Boolean
Dim NextTick As Date, t As Date
Sub StartStopWatch()
t = Time
Call StartTimer
End Sub

Sub StartTimer()
NextTick = Time + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Range("M1").Value = Format(NextTick - t - TimeValue("00:00:01"), "hh:mm:ss")
If blResume = False Then Exit Sub
Application.OnTime NextTick, "StartTimer"
End Sub
Sub Pause()
    blResume = False
End Sub
Sub myResume()
    blResume = True
    StartTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be running when I click start. Is it accidentally reading blresume as false when it starts? Is there a way to set it to true before the script runs so that it runs the starttimer sub?

Comment: To set it ture  run myresume.